# How to Extract the Title from the Wikipedia API

Tags: php, arrays, json, wikipedia-api

This is probably a obvious answer that I'm just not getting as I've been at this for a few hours now. So from this [Wikipedia API query](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srnamespace=0&srlimit=1&srinterwiki=&format=json&srenablerewrites=&redirects=&srsearch=Google) I got this response

```
{"batchcomplete":"","continue":{"sroffset":1,"continue":"-||"},"query":{"searchinfo":{"totalhits":173918},"search":[{"ns":0,"title":"Google","snippet":"search engine, see Google Search. For other uses, see Google (disambiguation). Not to be confused with Goggle\u00a0or Googol. Google Inc. is an American","size":143977,"wordcount":13927,"timestamp":"2015-11-25T08:44:48Z"}]}}
```

Which I have converted into this php Array

```
Array
(
[batchcomplete] => 
[continue] => Array
    (
        [sroffset] => 1
        [continue] => -||
    )

[query] => Array
    (
        [searchinfo] => Array
            (
                [totalhits] => 173918
            )

        [search] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [ns] => 0
                        [title] => Google
                        [snippet] => search engine, see Google Search.  For other uses, see Google (disambiguation). Not to be confused with GoggleÂ or Googol. Google Inc. is an American
                        [size] => 143977
                        [wordcount] => 13927
                        [timestamp] => 2015-11-25T08:44:48Z
                    )

            )

    )

)
```

And I am trying to use this code to extract the Title entity from the Array

```
echo $array->query->search->0->title;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you using object syntax when accessing array values?

Comment: assuming the title will ***always be in the same place*** you need `$array['query']['search'][0]['title']` where $array is the name of the variable the array is stored in. what you are trying to do is to call a function or variable from an object.....which is still wrong as you would neverhave a function/variable named `0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have used is for stdClass objects,

```
echo $array->query->search->0->title;
```

replace `->` with `[]`

```
echo $array['query']['search'][0]['title'];
```

Comment: Working fine with this??

Comment: ANY object.. not specifically stdClass objects.